# Blazor - Handling Multiple Parents

Tags: blazor

I have 2 components **The Parents**, both with:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div class="col-12 outer-div row">
        <TaskDetails TaskId="@AddedTaskId" IsVisible="@IsTaskDetailsVisible"></TaskDetails>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
...
@code{
    public void RemoveTaskDetails()
    {
        IsTaskDetailsVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And on **The Child**

```
[CascadingParameter]
public TaskList _Parent { get; set; }
[CascadingParameter]
public NewTask _Parent { get; set; }
...
private void ToggleVisibility()
{
    _Parent.RemoveTaskDetails();
}
```

Obviously I can't have both Parents named the same, but is there an actual way to achieve this?

Can I have an anonymous way to assign a Parent to a component? (Similar to  overloading a method I guess)

What's the workaround if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an interface:

```
// ITaskParent.cs
interface ITaskParent { void ToggleVisibility(); }
```

```
// TaskList.razor
@implements ITaskParent

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    ...
</CascadingValue>

@code{
   public void ToggleVisibility() { ... }
}
```

```
// NewTask.razor 
@implements ITaskParent

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    ...
</CascadingValue>

@code{
   public void ToggleVisibility() { ... }
}
```

and

```
// TaskDetails.razor

[CascadingParameter]
public ITaskParent  TaskParent { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm failing to see how to apply an interface to the components.

Comment: @Henrique There are two ways.  (1) You can put your component code in a separate file, and derive the component from ComponentBase as well as the interface.  (2) You can use the `@implements` keyword in your .razor markup

Comment: With `@implements ITaskParent`

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - I'm not sure that (1) will work. I'll have to try.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, I think a class can implement as many interfaces as you want, no?

Comment: I checkled, it works. I wasn't sure about merging the 2 parts (1 with base class and 1 with the interface) of the partial class but that's Ok.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean for me to to. Could you point me with some tutorial, example or documentation please?

Comment: I've expanded a little. The discussion above is about using code-behind, a different approach.

Comment: I would probably do `<CascadingValue TValue="ITaskParent" Value="(ITaskParent)this">
` to make things obvious to a third party what I was passing, but that's only being picky!